# How do I copy a worksheet without creating local copies of workbook-scoped named formulas?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a workbook with some workbook-scoped named formulas. When I copy a worksheet that has some (different) worksheet-scoped names, the copy ends up also having worksheet-scoped names that are identical (other than scope) to the workbook-scoped names.

Example: Say the workbook has workbook-scoped name 'a', the worksheet has worksheet-scoped name 'b'. The copy of the worksheet ends up with 'b' (as expected), *and* a worksheet-scoped name 'a' that refers to the same formula that the workbook-scoped 'a' does.

I guess I haven't used named formulas enough to have noticed that this is how Excel works, but it's definitely not how I *want* it to work. Does anyone know how to copy sheets without spewing extra names everywhere? (This includes the related question of how to copy a worksheet from onw workbook to another without also copying over all the workbook-scoped names from the source workbook.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, here is my [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/171216/is-there-a-way-to-copy-an-excel-worksheet-without-copying-all-of-the-cell-styles/171225#171225) from your [follow-up question](https://superuser.com/questions/171216) that ended up working:

> You should be able to select all of the cells in the original worksheet, copy them, and then "paste special" (Edit > Paste Special) in the target workbook. From within the "paste special" dialog, you can specify only formulas, values, etc. and omit style information.

Comment: I'll accept this too unless there is a more direct answer soon. Thanks again!

Comment: As with my other question, this answer gets me what I need for convenience in my case. If I were trying to automate this and copy code behind the worksheet, etc., it's not complete. Note that copying cells seems to copy local defined names that are actually used by the copied cells, but not any other local names. (In my case, though what I care about is *not* creating a local copy of a workbook-scoped name, and this satisfies that need.)

Answer (score 0):

In current versions of Excel you can easily remove all the names scoped to the new worksheet through the Name Manager.

Open the name manager using either:

- Old shortcut: Alt, I, N, D
- Ribbon: Formulas -> (Defined Names) Name Manager

Then:

- Sort by 'Scope' by clicking on the 'Scope' header
- Select the first name that refers to the sheet in question
- Hold 'Control' and click the last name that refers to the sheet in question
- Click 'Delete'
- Click 'Close'