# Is there a way to copy an Excel worksheet without copying all of the cell styles in the source workbook to the target workbook?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, copy-paste, styles, microsoft-excel-2010

The title pretty much says it. I have an Excel document with tons of randomly named styles that I didn't create but that I want to copy a worksheet from. When I do, it drags all of those styles into my target workbook, which I don't want. None of the styles themselves are used on the actual sheet I am copying.

If I can't prevent this, is there a way to delete a bunch of styles as a group, rather than selecting each and deleting it?

This other question of mine is similar, in that the problem I'm having is that I get garbage I don't want (and that I don't see that *any* user wants) when I copy a worksheet:

[How do I copy a worksheet without creating local copies of workbook-scoped named formulas?](https://superuser.com/questions/167825/how-do-i-copy-a-worksheet-without-creating-local-copies-of-workbook-scoped-named)

It earned a "tumbleweed" badge, but perhaps whoever answers this will have an answer for it as well...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to select all of the cells in the original worksheet, copy them, and then "paste special" (`Edit > Paste Special`) in the target workbook. From within the "paste special" dialog, you can specify only formulas, values, etc. and omit style information.

Disclaimer: I haven't tried this with Excel 2007 or higher. I'm stuck on the old version.

Comment: Actually, I want everything except the styles in the source workbook that the source sheet doesn't use, so it can be even simpler. I can just select all of the cells in the source sheet, copy them, and paste them *without* Paste...Special. It does create a "Normal2" style, but it's just one to delete. I don't know why I've never thought to copy a sheet by copying all of its cells instead of copying the whole tab by the "Move or Copy" dialog. Thanks! Definite +1, and I'll formally accept this answer if nobody has anything even more direct.

Comment: this should work for my other question too, if you want to answer that and get credit...

Comment: Accepted. While not precisely the solution, it's good enough for me. I'm not trying to automate this - just to eliminate the inconvenience of deleting all the superfluous styles. Obviously, this method won't copy code behind the sheet, etc., but I don't care about that.